# Facebook native ads won't click at first and second positions of recycler view

Tags: android, facebook, android-recyclerview, facebook-audience-network, native-ads

I have an android app where I am using Facebook Audience Network for displaying native ads to my user.

I am using a recycler view for displaying a list.

The problem that I am facing is that the ads are not clickable when I put them at the first and second position of my recycler view.The same code is working fine in other position (>2).

Can anyone help me with this in any way?

Comment: Can you attach code of RecyclerView.Adapter (your implementation) and Holder with native ads.

Comment: I can't actually I have some restrictions

Answer (score 0):

Worth a try:  use the `onTouchEvent` of the RecyclerView, check if the facebook ad's `getGlobalVisibleRect` contains the `MotionEvent` coordinates and eventually pass this event and every following to this view.

It is not feasable to just dispatch a manual click event on the facebook ad.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I will definitely try it.